# CollectionViewCell is not changing its background color

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with views that change depending on a flag, if the flag is 1 it changes to green, if it is 0 it changes to red. But the first time it renders is not changing, but until I scroll and come back. The strange thing is that it changes correctly the icon, the texts, text color, etc. (which I don't show in this code) its just the background color thats not changing! What is happening?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SensorCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? SensorCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        //Fill with data. 

        if sensors[indexPath.row]["alert"] as? Int == 0 {
            cell.alertState.textColor = UIColor.white
            cell.background.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Tomato")
            //more things 
        }

        if sensors[indexPath.row]["alert"] as? Int == 1 { 
            cell.alertState.textColor = UIColor.white
            cell.background.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "KelleyGreen")
            //more things 
        }

        return cell
    }
```

```
import UIKit

class SensorCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sensorImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sensorType: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sensorValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var alertState: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var background: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bellIcon: UIImageView!


    static func loadFromNib() -> CardSensors {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SensorCell", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! CardSensors
    }

    func roundCorners(view :UIView, corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat){
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        view.layer.mask = mask
    }

    //Permite que no se dupliquen los estilos cuando se hace scroll rapido
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.background.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Grey")
        self.alertState.textColor = UIColor(named: "BrownGrey")
        self.alertState.text = NSLocalizedString("notification_inactive", comment: "")
        self.bellIcon.image = UIImage(named: "bell_grey")
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        sensorImage.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0) //Le da el color gris y el circulo gris de cada sensor
        sensorImage.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        self.roundCorners(view: background, corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 9.0)
    }
}
```

### Update 1

I tried to add `layoutSubviews()` and `layoutIfNeeded()`

The cells are changing but the not the first time they are created.

Comment: what is exactly `background` property in cell? Show us `SensorCell` implementation.

Comment: background is just a view that has an icon and a label

Comment: 1. Set breakpoint and check that `background` is initialised
2. Recheck "alert" vs "alerta" - is there typo?
3. Try to do the same with `contentView` of cell

Comment: You don't do anything in the case where `alert` is *neither*  0 or 1 (e.g. if it is `nil`)

Comment: @Paulw11 nil is the default. So it is the grey color I have in the xib

Comment: @SergeyGamayunov all fine, alert vs alerta was a typo in my question only

Comment: Your round corners code is wrong too.

Comment: Then as suggested, set a breakpoint to see what is happening.

Comment: @matt why tho?  What is wrong? It works perfectly

Comment: There are easier ways to round corners, e.g. `layer.cornerRadius = <whatever>; layer.masksToBounds = true`.

Comment: The code is being executed 4 times, the first time when its created. Then when it loads in background the rest of the data, when is showed after vertical scroll (here i can see it for the first time) and last when I scroll the collectionView back

Comment: @NRitH I don't want to give round corners to all corners, but thank you

Comment: Also recheck, that you use right property of indexPath, sometimes we confused between sections and items. Also it is good practice to use "rows" for tableView and items for collectionView.

Comment: @SergeyGamayunov yes, I'm using the correct property, I'll use it as items now! thanks